# Tortoise Git Merge Conflict Colors

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit, tortoisemerge, tortoisegitmerge

What do the colors mean when resolving conflicts in TortoiseGit?

E.g: There's a conflict in a file, and there's text highlighted with orange in the "theirs" window, and yellow in the "mine" window. And of course, the red text highlighted.

My confusion is that I'm not sure what code from each file is being added to the final file.

I've looked online for a definition of what the different colours mean, or a settings page to customize them (which would be equally good) but I can't find either.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Wow...I feel sheepish. In the Tortoise git diff window, in the top left, there's an arrow pointing down. Clicking this opens "Settings" with a tab for "Colors".

Comment: I would have NEVER found that. And clearly at least 4 people found this helpful!

Comment: I use TortoiseGitMerge 2.5.0.0 and there is no "Settings" in the menu of that little arrow. Now you have to click on the big round button to the left of that arrow.

Comment: Although I found the color legend, the colors in tortoise git merge don't make sense for me. It colours line, which wasn't there before, as deleted etc. Is there any deeper explanation, what the colors do mean? For example in TFS there are green and red changes and it is clear immediately, what gets into the result. Here I don't understand the result and try to put there everything and then manually change later.

Comment: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegitmerge/tmerge-dug-settings.html#tmerge-dug-settings-color

Comment: In version 2.5.7, the "Settings" option is under the File menu.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a screen shot of the default settings for your reference.

[image: Color settings pane with defaults]